# am trying to make a button that you can drag.I realize that I can simulate onPress events with onPanResponderRelease

Tags: react-native, panresponder

am trying to make a button that you can drag. I realize that I can simulate onPress events with onPanResponderRelease, but it doesn't work on some Android devices.

When I try wrapping a Touchable element with an Animated.View with panHandlers, the pan responder gets touch priority and the Touchable element's onPress prop doesn't get called. Is there a way to have both the Touchable element's onPress function and PanResponder config methods get called simultaneously?

https://snack.expo.dev/@shafhadkhan/panresponder